# Java - How to pass a paramter to an if statement "if "F(x)" found, pass "x" to the F function

Tags: java, function, if-statement, parameter-passing

What im doing is making a production rule in the form of a string of a finite alphabet, copy it into a char array and then run it through an if statement which calls functions depending on the character.

Such as "lff[f]" which calls functionL, functionF, functionF, functionOpenB, functionF, functionCloseB.

So currently its:

```
workRuleArr= stringProdrule.toCharArray();
for  (char c=0; c < workRuleArr.length; c++){
    if (workRuleArr[c] == 'f')
     {
          functionF();

      }
      if (workRuleArr[c] == 'l')
     {
          functionL();

      }
```

etc

This is fine and working, however:

How would i pass parameters to those functions from the production rule such as "l(100)ff.." so that it would call functionL(x)... where x is = 100 and pass 100 to the function??

And there may be many different values for x in the same production rule string. The user inputs the rule in one go at the start o the program so it would need to deal with multiple parameters in the same production rule

Any ideas would be appreciated, if the question is not clear let me know. Thanks

Comment: oh, and a general tip besides my answer: use equals(..) instead of ==.

Comment: Dont use `char` as type for counters. Use `int`.

Answer (score 5):

Seems to me that those "rule functions" you have all serve a similar purpose, so they obey the same interface,
like

```
interface Rule{
    void executeRule();
}
```

Then you have different Rules that implement that interface, like

```
class RuleF implements Rule{
        void executeRule(){
            //execute rule F
        }
}

class RuleL implements Rule{
        void executeRule(){
            //execute rule L
        }
}
```

Then you need a simple way to associate a character with a given rule.
Use a HashMap, like:

```
Map<Character, Rule> ruleMap = new HashMap<Character, Rule>();
ruleMap.add('f', new RuleF());
ruleMap.add('l', new RuleL());
```

With that you can remove all those "ifs", like

```
workRuleArr= stringProdrule.toCharArray();
for  (char c=0; c < workRuleArr.length; c++){
    Rule rule = ruleMap.get(workRuleArr[c]);
    rule.executeRule();
}
```

Now if you need that the Rule interface receives a parameter,
you'll also need a similar Map object to associate the character with the parameter you need to pass.

What exactly are you building? Some sort of state machine?

cheers, good luck! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). You are basically asking for the answer that this question

Answer (score 1):

looks like you need some sort of parser that'll give you valid tokens, or will need to jerry rig your own.  Whatever the case, you'll need to look one step ahead in your array.
here's yet another implementation:

```
String rule = "FLL(123)FKF";

String pattern = "[a-zA-Z]{1}|[(\\d)]+"; //any single character or set of (numbers)
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = p.matcher(rule);

String command = "", param = "", token;

while(m.find()){
  token = m.group();

  if(token.length() > 1){  //must be parameter
    param = token.substring(1, token.length()-1);
    continue;
  }

  if(command != ""){
    runCommand(command, param);
    param = "";  //clear
  }
  command = token;  //set next
}

if(command != "")    //last trailing run
  runCommand(command, param);
```

Also need to define runCommand:

```
bool runCommand(string command, string param){
  System.out.println("execute function" + command + "(" + param + ")");

  bool success, hasParam = (param != "");
  int p = Integer.parseInt(param);

  switch(command){
    case "F":
      success = (hasParam ? functionF() : functionF(p));
      break;
    case "L":
      success = (hasParam ? functionL() : functionL(p));
      break;
    case "K":
      success = (hasParam ? functionK() : functionK(p));
      break;
  }
  return success;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a simple if statement to test whether there is a parameter or not:

```
workRuleArr= stringProdrule.toCharArray();

for  (char c=0; c < workRuleArr.length; c++){

    if (workRuleArr[c] == 'f') {

        if(workRuleArr[c+1].equals("(")) {

            // use the parameter
            String param = "";

            c++;

            while(!workRuleArr[c+1].equals(")")) {
                param += workRuleArr[c+1];
                c++;
            }

            int yourParameter = Integer.parseInt(param);

            functionF(yourParameter);
        }
        else {

            functionF();
        }
    }
    if (workRuleArr[c] == 'l'){

        functionL();
    }
}
```

Please note, I haven't tested the code, there can be some errors.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't convert into a char array, because String has more and useful methods, also for this case.

So, for each character with index `i` you need to test if the char at `i+1` is '(', then use `int k = stringProdrule.indexOf(')', i+2)` to get the closing parenthesis and pass the string between both parentheses as parameter to the function. Then continue at `k+1`.